# Make observable call synchronous in angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular8, angular9

I am using observable for HTTP request I want to make it as a synchronous call since am new to rxjs. And below code am using to doing the multiple calls, so after the completion of all the calls only I have to call the drive method. I referred a lot of links but I could not understand pls help me.

ServicecallApi:

```
public createHttpRequests(
    method: string,
    url: string,
    payload?: any,
    params?: any,
 
  ): Observable<any> {
    switch ((method).toLowerCase()) {
      case 'get': return this.createHttpGet(url, params);
      case 'post': return this.createHttpPost(url, payload);
      default: return this.http.get('');
    }
  }
```

And my service call is below:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {


this.serviceCall.createHttpRequests('get', this.someService.getUserList, {}, {}).pipe(
  map((result: Iuserlist) => {
    if (result.body.statusCode ===  200) {
    
    } else {
   
    }
  }),
).subscribe();
this.serviceCall.createHttpRequests('get', this.someService.getsomeData, {}, {}).pipe(
  map((result: Isomedatas) => {
    if (result.body.statusCode ===  200) {
    
    } else {
   
    }
  }),
).subscribe();

//This method should call after the above api completion 
this.getDriverDetails();
 }
```

Comment: Do not make synchronous web requests. It's not just observables that are asynchronous it's the underline browsers HTTP requests. I understand that RX can be a bit overwhelming but you don't have to use RX. Promise based asynchronous requests, which now have the async await syntactic sugar, are easy to understand and easy to learn.

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you can use `combineLatest` function from `rxjs`.

Use below code.

```
public createHttpRequests(
  method: string,
  url: string,
  payload? : any,
  params? : any,

): Observable<any> {
  switch ((method).toLowerCase()) {
    case 'get':
      return this.createHttpGet(url, params);
    case 'post':
      return this.createHttpPost(url, payload);
    default:
      return this.http.get('');
  }
}
// And my service call is below:
public ngOnInit(): void {
  const userList$ = this.serviceCall.createHttpRequests('get', this.someService.getUserList, {}, {}).pipe(
    map((result: Iuserlist) => {
      if (result.body.statusCode === 200) {

      } else {

      }
    }),
  );

  const someData$ = this.serviceCall.createHttpRequests('get', this.someService.getsomeData, {}, {}).pipe(
    map((result: Isomedatas) => {
      if (result.body.statusCode === 200) {

      } else {

      }
    }),
  );

  combineLatest([userList$, someData$]).subscribe(([userList, someData]) => {
    console.log(userList);
    console.log(userList);

    this.getDriverDetails();
  });
}
```

Comment: let me try this one.then why we use forkjoin and merge map,flat map can you please tell me am new to rxjs it feels like tough to learn

Comment: These are different functions for rxjs. You can read the difference between them from google. And Please accept my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Making an observable synchronous is possible with [async/await](https://www.techiediaries.com/javascript-async-await-tutorial/), but it is a bad idea in my opinion, a better approach would be using [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin), since you want to execute a code once 2 observables have been completed.

```
forkJoin({
  firstService: this.firstService$,
  secondService: this.secondService$});
.subscribe({
 next: value => {
  //this  will run once both observables are completed. 
  console.log(value); 
  // Logs:
  // { firstService: response, secondService: response, } 
  //call your function here 
  this.getDriverDetails();
  }
});
```